# $resource caching: What's the difference between cache: true and cache: obj

Tags: angularjs, caching

As the title states, I'm using a $resource object to do a GET request.

Can someone who has in-depth knowledge explain the difference when setting
cache: true

```
query: {
    method: 'GET',
    cache: true
}
```

**VS** having something like:

```
var theCache = $cacheFactory('myCache');
```

and using that cache object on the resource by doing this:

```
query: {
    method: 'GET',
    cache: theCache
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing the `true` parameter, you're telling angular to use the default (global) `$http` cache, which means the response will be cached and every next request made through `$http` or `$resource` (which is a high-level abstraction over the `$http`) will be served from cache (no extra requests to the server). The key for this request in the `$http` cache is the full-path URL. You can obtain the default `$http` cache instance using the `$cacheFactory`:

```
var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
```

Now, if you want to create a resource-specific cache you create it using the `$cacheFactory` and tell the `$http` or `$resource` to use it:

```
var myCache = $cacheFactory.get('myCache');

$http.get('/api/users.json', {
    cache: myCache
});

// or 

$resource('/api/users.json', null, {
        query: { cache: myCache }
});
```

This way no other requests will be sharing this cache anymore. Additionally, you can specify the `capacity` of this cache while instantiating it, or clear it whenever you need to without affecting the other service.